# Different fields of same content type to different roles

Tags: entities, rules, actions

I have a content type 'new resource'.

I have the form displayed as a page. I would like to make it so that form contains an image field for the admin role, but have this field hidden for any anonymous user filling out the form.

I have been trying to use 'Rules':

EVENTS content is viewed

CONDITION content is of type... Parameter: Content: [node], Content types: new resource AND... NOT User has role(s)... Parameter: User: [node:author], Roles: administrator

ACTIONS Remove an item from a list
Parameter: List: [node:field-web-resource..., Item to remove: [node:field-web-resource..

This might be completely the wrong way to do it, and there is a simpler way, or the Rules approach might work.

When I try to add the ACTIONS the dropdown box keeps showing me things like this:
node:field-web-resource-image-main:0 (Image)
node:field-web-resource-image-main:1 (Image)
node:field-web-resource-image-main:2 (Image)
node:field-web-resource-image-main:3 (Image)

I'm guessing that this is because I have an unlimited amount of images available for upload in this field.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [field permission module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to set permission on the field level.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/build/modules/list and enable "Content Permissions" under the cck group.

Then go to /admin/user/permissions. Here under "content_permissions module" section  enable permissions for the fields you want to be displayed for authenticated users or anonymous users.

Comment: Is this D7 or D6? I'm on D7.

Comment: @njwrigley I'm Sorry, the above answer was for D6. For D7  go to /admin/people/permissions. There under the "node" group, enable permissions for the fields to be displayed for authenticated users or anonymous users.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I was after something which  would hide 1 specific field with a content type based upon the user role. This did the trick nicely: http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions. It allows you to set custom permissions within a content type so that, say the image field is not visible on the SUBMIT FORM for anonymous users, but is visible for admins.